# JMSTransationBundle is translating the contents of all arrays with 'label' as a key

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I understand that the most recent JMSTranslationBundle automatically translates form labels, but it appears to be translating ANY php array element with the key 'label'.

Here is my test file:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
   $WTF = array( 'label' => 'WHY IS THIS BEING TRANSLATED?');
   return $this->render('MyAppSomeBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('x' => $WTF) );
}
```

If I run the command:

```
./app/console translation:extract fr --output-dir=./app/Resources/ --bundle=MyAppSomeBundle --keep
```

The JMSTranslationBunlde finds the $WTF array and translates it:

```
      <trans-unit id="4b68507f1746b0e5f3efe99b8ef42afef79da017" resname="WHY IS THIS BEING TRANSLATED">
        <source>WHY IS THIS BEING TRANSLATED</source>
        <target state="new">WHY IS THIS BEING TRANSLATED</target>
        <jms:reference-file line="11">Some/Controller/DefaultController.php</jms:reference-file>
      </trans-unit>
```

Is anyone else experiencing this? Is there a workaround?

Also note that if I change 'label' to something else (such as 'notlabel'), the translation doesn't occur.

Comment: looks like you've found a bug. Why not report it ?

Answer (score 1):

The label gets extracted because of the form label translation stuff.

Have you tried using the @ignore annotation?

```
$wtf = array('label' => /** @Ignore */ 'This should not get translated');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The challenge with using annotation is that there are literally thousands of places in the legacy system that may be subject to this translation wizardry. I'm hoping that there is a config setting that can be enabled, or a simple way to override the messaging class responsible for finding labels.

Comment: I came across this problem and for some reason, the version I was using didn't work, I found [this PR (Setting @Ignore to fully ignore the string #194)](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle/pull/194) so I forked the plugin and merged PR and `/** @Ignore */` now works again.